# How do I know to add a layer to my neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

As I develop small prototypes of a single hidden-layer back-propagating NN, w/ sigmoid activation, I have moved from training it with very basic data and outputs, to wanting to train the famous Iris data.

(http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)

This data has 3 outputs, and has been built in to many example NN implementations almost as a proof that it works. 4 inputs, 1x6 hidden, 3 outputs (which can almost be read as the chance it is one of the 3 species).

When I attempt to train it on this data, the total output error fluctuates quite a lot, regardless of the 1000 or even 50000 iterations.

Can I see this as an indicator to add another hidden layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - no. Iris is nearly linearly separable, you do not need any additional hidden layers to solve it (have nearly 100% accuracy).